# Sharepoint Foundation: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing'"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepointfoundation2010

I deployed some solutions to Sharepoint Central Administration. 
After this, the Central Administration can't open. this error appear when I try access the site:

> Error
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I saw at some blog this error occur because the solution isn't compatible with sharepoint foundation.
So I uninstalled all solutions from site using PowerShell's Command. But the error persist.

What I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Is the site a publishing site?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you only have SharePoint Foundation installed since you get this error, (and not SharePoint Server).
I would check the web.config of the central admin website for references to 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing'. Probably the custom solutions you installed left some traces there and that's causing your problem. It's not pretty but you'll probably need to remove these references manually.